# How to graph square root function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

How to graph the this square root function
$$f(x) = \sqrt {x^2-8x+16}$$

with steps

Comment: Can you factor?

Comment: Plug it into a graphing calculator. A question how to graph something is too vague without context- what properties are you looking for when you graph?

Comment: Domain , Range , monotony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factorize $x^{2}-8x+16$ gets $(x-4)^{2}$, so the function becomes $|x-4|$. If you know how to draw $y=|x|$, then $y=|x-4|$ is just the right shift to $4$ unit.